# Magento 2.3.0 robots.txt file location in server directory

Tags: magento2.3, seo, robots.txt

I am trying to delete a `disallow` condition from `robots.txt` file. This is not located in `root` or `/pub directories`.

I can't change it from admin panel because seems like **Magento 2.3.0** has a bug on theme edit page.

> [Github thread for details](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19549)

Thanks

Comment: Can you give robots.txt link here?

Comment: Sure, Here is the link https://www.mkelectronicsbd.com/robots.txt

Comment: From the look of your web source robots.txt should be in /pub directory. Please also check .htaccess, if robots.txt is somehow rewrite

Comment: I have created a new robots.txt file in `root` directory. newly created file now showing on website. I don't know why!

Answer (score 4):

It seems your Nginx or Apache is set differently. Try locating the file in var directory. If you have SSH access, run below command to see if there is a robots file on server.

Check if there is a robots file on server `locate -c robots.txt`

If the result found is greater than 0, it means the file exists on the server. Next, you can run below command to find the location

`locate robots.txt`

Comment: Found some robots.txt files with this method but that file is missing. Now I have created a new robots.txt file in `root` directory. newly created file now showing on website. I don't know why!

Comment: Thanks your answer is helpful and i am using nginx server and i have checked this way and it's showing here https://prnt.sc/qvh0mg but i want to edit file how can possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Magento2.3.5 have a module to return a robots.txt page so is not finically in the server in a location.
See Ref: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Robots/Controller/Index/Index.php in `execute()` method.

Also look in controller Router.php to have an idea!

Hope it helps!